# running a blazemeter script against microsoft edge

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I have recorder a blazemeter script. Can I run it against edge by editing the User-Agent? I have refered the below url to check the User Agent for edge, but could not find one
What should be my user agent if I need to run the same script against Edge?
Currently it is like below
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run Edge, open any website and check what's being sent in [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header in the developer tools:

[image]

The above example is for the "old" Edge, the "new" one which is based on Chromium has [slightly different user agent string](http://Microsoft%20Edge%20User%20Agent%20String%20(Desktop)):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.74 Safari/537.36 Edg/79.0.309.43
```

I also think that you're not sending all the required headers, for example [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) and [Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) are missing and the latter one has huge impact on the amount of the data transferred over the wire.

More information: [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)

Answer (score 0):

jMeter is load testing tool which sends bunch of api requests to server by particular endpoint.
When we do load testing, we are more interested in knowing the server performance. Not the client's browser performance.
Do you have any requirements to check load by particular header/agent?and what are you going to check exactly?
Answering on your question, just add any valid microsoft EDGE agent to your header/User Agent value.
Browser makes difference for UI testing, with tools like Selenium, but not API.